# Display loading view after login in ios 3 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking

I am trying to display a new view in IOS after login in  my application. I also want to display this view when I start the application if the user is already logged in this app.

Now, if I start the application the first time I have the login view and I can write my user name and my password. when I press send button(login) the next controller starts. I would like to set for 2 or 3 seconds one view while I am downloading the information from the web service. I don't care if the information comes faster than the two seconds because I want to wait this time. I save the user information in `NSUserdefaults`.

Next time I start the app I already have the information and I go directly to the next viewcontroller without see any login view. So I want to watch the loading view.

I use AFNetworking to consume my web services.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, it seems a little arbitrary to show it for 2 seconds, but you can present the view and then:

```
[myView performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] afterDelay:3.0];
```

Or what you probably should do is hide the view or set it to nil within the completion block of your AFNetworking Call, that way if the call takes longer than 2-3 seconds, the view won't disappear

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method for hiding view after delay using this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, using GCD:

1. Store the login information into keychain (`NSUserDefaults` are just plain unsafe for passwords!) and dismiss the login window immediately after it is saved.
2. When the loding view is shown, create a dispatch group and submit your login and download logic there. (`com.example.login` thread)
3. Use NSTimer (or any appropriate logic) to wait for 3 seconds, then spawn another thread in GCD (`com.example.login-wait` thread), call dispatch_group_wait to block that thread until the `com.example.login` thread is done, and submit a block back to the main queue to switch views.

I used this login in multiple applications and it looked fantastic.